# How can I include a HTML page in another HTML page

Tags: html, include

I am developing a website where I create different graphics with D3.js

I have a main page called "index.html" where I have a piece of text for the introduction. I have a second page called "GenrePie.html" which has a pie chart.

I want to put the "GenrePie.html" page in my "index.html" page.

On several forums I found a way to do it but it doesn't work for me :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#includedPieContent").load("GenrePie.html");
        });
    </script>
```

this is my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Maxes</title>


</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 id="title">Forever</h1>
        <p  id="intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id mi vitae felis faucibus finibus eu nec arcu. Curabitur quis ultricies magna. Cras rutrum metus est, id hendrerit mauris mattis a. Etiam suscipit sodales urna eget fringilla. Donec diam lorem, laoreet commodo ligula nec, mollis mattis mi. Mauris luctus ut nisi ac viverra. Integer dictum eu mi a aliquet. </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="principal">
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id mi vitae felis faucibus finibus eu nec arcu. Curabitur quis ultricies magna. Cras rutrum metus est, id hendrerit mauris mattis a. Etiam suscipit sodales urna eget fringilla. Donec diam lorem, laoreet commodo ligula nec, mollis mattis mi. Mauris luctus ut nisi ac viverra. Integer dictum eu mi a aliquet. 
</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to put my pie chart after the second paragraph

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use embed or iframe whichever suits you,

I will recommend embed as its looks clean.

**Quick Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/vikas_saini/kupb0Lh9/5/

```
<div>
    <h1>SOME TEXT</h1>

    <embed src="https://example.com/" style="width:500px; height: 300px;">

    <iframe src="https://example.com/">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>

</div>
```

Your Code Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Maxes</title>


</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 id="title">Forever</h1>
        <p  id="intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id mi vitae felis faucibus finibus eu nec arcu. Curabitur quis ultricies magna. Cras rutrum metus est, id hendrerit mauris mattis a. Etiam suscipit sodales urna eget fringilla. Donec diam lorem, laoreet commodo ligula nec, mollis mattis mi. Mauris luctus ut nisi ac viverra. Integer dictum eu mi a aliquet. </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="principal">
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id mi vitae felis faucibus finibus eu nec arcu. Curabitur quis ultricies magna. Cras rutrum metus est, id hendrerit mauris mattis a. Etiam suscipit sodales urna eget fringilla. Donec diam lorem, laoreet commodo ligula nec, mollis mattis mi. Mauris luctus ut nisi ac viverra. Integer dictum eu mi a aliquet. 
</p>
  <embed src="GenrePie.html" style="width:500px; height: 300px;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this did not work for you.